# static method in Python not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning by my self Python and I have a mind blowing issue, because I don't understand why is not working. I'm using PyDev and I've download version 2 of Python. I have this code:

```
class Utils:

    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print "Hi! I'm the Utils class"

Utils.hello() #Hi! I'm the Utils class
```

and everything is working fine at this point. But if I import the Utils class and call the static method from another module...

```
import Utils

Utils.hello()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\migugonz\Desktop\Docs\Per Folder\WorkSpacePy\Rosalind\src\bioinformatics\stronghold\Pruebas.py", line 40, in <module>
    Utils.hello()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hello'
```

I thing it can't be a big deal, but I've been searching a solution and as long I know this shlould be work.

Comment: Python is not php: you don't need classes to emulate namespaces. Just make `hello` a global function in Utils.

Comment: Python is not Java, there is absolutely no reason to have a class here, especially if all it contains is static methods. Just put `hello` at the top level of the file.

Comment: Thank you all. It's true, I come from Java and I use to have a static class for reusable methods. May be it's better way to do it like you say, thg435. Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't agree. I also come from Java and I want to put static method on another file, as a (good) way to separate responsibilities and also for re-usability purposes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you need to do `Utils.Utils.hello()`

or import like `from Utils import Utils`

Comment: This is why PEP8 suggests that modules should have all lowercase names. If @Hannibaal had used `utils.py` as the name for the module there wouldn't have been scope to confuse the module and class.

Comment: For now on my modules will be lowercase. I was confused because in java the name of the file (working with eclipse) is the class itself.